# How to configured Form Builder Js in my custom magento 2.3.0 module?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, adminform, magento2.3.0, ui-form

How can I configure below "**Form builder js**" in **Magento 2.3.0** custom extension?

```
https://github.com/dobtco/formbuilder
```

I want to use this js in my custom Extension's form in the admin side.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following way to add JS in admin:

Create file **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml** or add following code for JS in your custom module's admin layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Vendor_ModuleName::js/formbuilder.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

You can put your **formbuilder.js** in following path.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/formbuilder.js**

Please check and let me know if any issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what if I want to add in form rather than the system config ?

Comment: yes you can add this code in your form's layout.xml file

Comment: please share me your form's layout file so I will guide you how to add.

Comment: I want the same form as you can see in this screenshot :https://www.screencast.com/t/881sEzsmT

Comment: Did you create any module for that ?

Comment: Yes, and I have added js and  CSS in form layout file as you described. Plz help me I will accept your answer also upvote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89543/discussion-between-aasim-goriya-and-sanjay-gohil).